# React Distribute Chips Table Cells with rows 5 cells wide

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I want to create a table in my React functional component using hooks and the react material ui. I have an array of strings and I want to create a chip for each string in a table cell like so:

```
<TableCell>
     <Chip
        key={index}
        className={classes.chips}
        size="large"
        label={user}
        icon={<AccountCircleIcon className={classes.closeIcon}/>}
      />
 </TableCell>
```

I display an array of chips with

```
<div className={classes.chipContainer}> {Object.values(selectedUsersToDelete).map((user, index) => {
      return (
        <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
          <Chip
            key={index}
            className={classes.chips}
            size="large"
            label={user}
            icon={<AccountCircleIcon className={classes.closeIcon}/>}
          />
        </TableCell><TableCell>
          <Chip
            key={index}
            className={classes.chips}
            size="large"
            label={user}
            icon={<AccountCircleIcon className={classes.closeIcon}/>}
          />
        </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )
    })}

    </div>
```

where selectedUsersToDelete is the value of useState.

I have tried every way of looping over the values in selectedUsersToDelete, but I cannot get react to render the table with the table rows 5 cells wide!

Also adding a deleteIcon and deletehandler to the Chip breaks them.

I'm trying to adapt this tutorial to use hooks: [tut](https://codesandbox.io/s/lej5l)

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I mean, where are you stuck at then?

Comment: I tried a lot of things! Latest was just taking the code exactly and setting the initial values with useState from a prop that's passed to the component

Comment: Ok so assuming `selectedUsersToDelete` is an array of 5 strings, you want to render 1 row with each element in its own cell? So 5 columns, correct?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: `Object.values(selectedUsersToDelete).map` only works if `selectedUsersToDelete` is an object.  if you are mapping a value that is already an array, you just need `selectedUsersToDelete.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// You'll need to add correct paths below
import AccountCircleIcon from './AccountCircleIcon';
import TableCell from './TableCell';
import TableRow from './TableRow';
import Chip from './Chip';

const ChipContainer = props => {
  // State is initialized here
  const [selectedUsersToDelete, setSelectedUsersToDelete] = useState([]);

  // Props destructred
  const { classes } = props;

  // Just an example showing how you can set state once componnent has mounted
  useEffect(
    () =>
      void setSelectedUsersToDelete([
        'user1',
        'user2',
        'user3',
        'user4',
        'user5'
      ]),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.chipContainer}>
      <TableRow>
        {selectedUsersToDelete.map((user, index) => (
          <TableCell>
            <Chip
              key={index}
              className={classes.chips}
              size="large"
              label={user}
              icon={<AccountCircleIcon className={classes.closeIcon} />}
            />
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChipContainer;
```

Comment: Can you show me this with the useState hook? It's when I introduce hooks it goes wrong

Comment: Sure.  Have a look at the code above.  Hopefully that should work.

Comment: That's awesome - thanks for the clear comments as well - this helps me a lot!